# Typing Brackets '[' ']' Within a Node in Tikz Q-Tree

Tags: tikz-trees, linguistics, syntax, tikz-qtree, qtree

I am trying to make a tree with Tikz Q-Tree wherein one of the nodes/the text shown needs to read: [+past]. However, brackets are used in the construction of the tree itself, so when I include them in a node, it produces an error. Is there a way for me to 'tell' XeLaTeX/Tikz that the brackets used there should be read as text rather than code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `forest` documentation at page 4 -- https://ctan.um.ac.ir/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[Z [{$K[+past]$}] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]